# Deploy Django on AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i am trying to upload my Django based application on AwsElasticBeanStalk. My project structure is like this

```
**untitled:**

    untitled:
        settings.py,urls.py,views.py,wsgi.py
    .ebextensions:
        django.config
    app1
    templates
```

Whenever i try to upload my zip file(I have tried with compressing only the items inside the outermost untitled folder so that after extracting there are only files not a parent folder) I get a error , Your WSGIPATH refers to a file that does not exist and after the application is deployed when I click on link I get this error:
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

My django.config file is this:
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath:untitled/wsgi.py

Can anybody tell me what is the problem? I have tried many hit and trials but this has been a dead end. Please help

Answer (score -1):

I've had this issue before. The problem was with how I zip the folder. Try selecting your folder content (.ebextentions, app folder etc) and not the outer folder and then zip.

P.S. I highly recommend using EB CLI to deploy your code. it's super easy to setup, and you won't have issues like this.

Comment: I'm getting this with EB CLI